# Android Spinner & CheckBox OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, android, checkbox

I am having some problem with the on trigger event of spinner and checkbox in android. So basically what I am trying to do is firstly when something from spinner was selected, my **tableOri** will appear. When the checkbox is checked, the tableOri will be hidden and replace with **tableSuggested**. Both of the tables should be **hidden at first**.

Here is my route_planning.xml:

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbMostCommuter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:text="Most Commuter Routes" />

<TableLayout 
     android:id = "@+id/tableOri"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0"
     android:padding="5dp">

 <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TextView
         android:text="10009"
         android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
     <TextView
         android:text="Bt Merah Int"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
     <TextView
         android:text="0 mins"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout 
     android:id = "@+id/tableSuggested"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0"
     android:padding="5dp">

 <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TextView
         android:text="10009"
         android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
     <TextView
         android:text="Bt Merah Int                          "
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
     <TextView
         android:text="0 mins"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
 </TableRow>
```

And the place where I execute all the onCLick event:

```
private CheckBox cbMostCommuter;
private Spinner spinner;
private static final String[]paths = {"Trunk Bus Service", "268", "269", "272", "275"};
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_planning);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            TableLayout tableOri = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableOri);
            tableOri.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            cbMostCommuter = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMostCommuter);
            cbMostCommuter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TableLayout tableOri = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableOri);
                    TableLayout tableSuggested = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableSuggested);
                    if(cbMostCommuter.isChecked() == true){
                        tableSuggested.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tableOri.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    else{
                        tableSuggested.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        tableOri.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

        }
    });
}
```

However, **both my tables were appearing even when there is nothing selected from spinner**.

And when I check and uncheck the checkbox, it did hide or show the table. But somehow the second table will not shift up if the first table is not there.

I wonder which part of my codes went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downvoter mind to point out the reason?

Comment: where you called `onItemSelected` or else you need to override it?

Comment: @shylendra I've edited my question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead of `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` in your java code. Secondly, use `android:visibility="gone"` in your table layouts. Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) to understand the difference between aforementioned states. 
 
 Do you use **RelativeLayout** as a parent of specified widgets?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved the problem. But the only problem left is when I first run the activity, even though there is nothing selected from the spinner, the tableOri still appear. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `android:visibility="gone"` attribute prevents the widget to appear on screen. Maybe your code shows it when your spinner or another view is being initialized...

Comment: I found out why is it so already. Because the first spinner item was selected by default. I included an if else statement to check the selected spinner value and perform the hide/show event. Thanks a lot!